# File Share files wont execute

Tags: network-share, windows-server-2016, file-sharing, uac

I have a Windows Server 2016 which is hosting a small file share. I have full control of the fileshare (from the root drive to every file) and even the "everyone" group have permission to execute files. There are no deny permissions. I'm able to create/delete files/folders and even open text files or word documents. However, I have a very strange behaviour when trying to run executables.

When I double click an executable file (*.exe, *.msi, *.bat) nothing happens -- No error messages are shown.

I can run these executable files successfully from cmd prompt without any errors. However desktop shortcuts do not work.

**What I've Tried:**

- Enabled access-based enumeration (can still see files)
- Removed all Group Policies from both the server and client computers,
- Re-installed Windows 10 Pro on numerous machines,
- Completely disabled UAC on client machines (using local admin account),
- [Configured GPO to **EnableLinkedConnections**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oktNT.png) for both server and computers,
- Set permissions for everyone to be able to execute files,
- Disabled firewalls on clients and server,
- Checked Event Viewer - unable to find associated logs on either client or server - *I may have missed this log where would it be located?*

All Machines are running Windows 10 Pro (1803) and are domain joined with Active Directory.

Additionally, I'm able to run these files on the server by going through the share path, detailed below. However this does not work on the client machines, it simply doesn't do anything.

**Share:** `\\Server\System\Software\`

Perhaps crucial to the issue, after I run `gpupdate /force` I am able to run these executables without any issue at all. What on earth could cause this? It stops working after signing out and I need to force gpupdate again. Issue persists after reboots.

If anyone could please help me I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you right-click on one of the files in the shares, you should get a menu. Do **open** and/or **run** and/or **run as administrator** appear in that menu? What happens if you select one of those choices? What kind of network connection is there between the client and server? Speed? LAN or WAN?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Right-Click>Run As Administrator has the same affect as double clicking - nothing happens. I receive all the options I'd expect under right-click and It's a LAN with 1 Gb/s.